# CPQ Quote templates selection problems

Tags: cpq, quote-template

I'm working on a CPQ implementation that I didn't originally set up, and I need to make some minor changes to the templates. Before making any modifications, I want to be able to clone and test new templates. While the changes themselves should be straightforward, the issue I'm encountering is that the template selector remains disabled when I attempt to create a new document from the quote. It consistently displays the same template, regardless of the Deployment Status and Default fields in the quote template record.

It always looks like this:

[image]

In fact, to remove the name of the company from the screenshot, I had to rename the template in the sandbox to 'ORIGINAL TEMPLATE'.

I don't know what else to try. I've tried cloning that template, setting the new cloned one as deployed and as the default, but the selector always displays the first one and doesn't allow me to change it.

I've also created a development organization with CPQ permissions from Trailhead, and when I try there, I'm not encountering these issues. So, I assume that there might be some configuration made by the teams that is no longer in place, causing the template to be locked. However, I'm not sure where to look for this configuration.

Any ideas?